# How to ask about a duration of a flight

Tags: tag-questions

if you have this answer to a question: 
The flight from America To United Kingdom is 5 hours.

How would you ask about the duration?

> 1- How long is the flight from America to UK?

Or

> 2- How far is the flight?

Comment: "To whom, did you give my car keys?"

Comment: I know but how about “Who did you give my keys to?” Is it valid?

Comment: This link will help you for the second question https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/who-did-you-give-the-book-to.2092129/

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker. For your first question, this is how I would ask "How long does it take to fly from America to England?".

Comment: I've removed the second question. Please ask only one question at a time.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn’t aware of this rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question, the correct question is 'How long' not 'How far' since you are asking about time not distance.

For your second question, 'who' is used for the subject and 'whom' is used for the object, although 'whom' is not common anymore. 'Who did you give my car keys to?' would be the standard question, although as Raj commented 'To whom did you give my car keys?' is equally valid.